# Check all parameters of an object contains empty value in scala

Tags: scala

I have a object called Address and it has few number of string parameters:

```
class Address(addressLine1: String, addressLine1: String, city: String, state: String) {

}
```

Now I want to create a methods which checks if all address parameters contains empty value:

```
def validateAddressNotEmpty(address: Address) : Boolean = {

//return true if any object parameter has non empty string

//return true if all object parameters contains  empty string

//NOTE: no parameter will contain NULL values 
  }
```

One way of doing this is to check each parameter separately. I am trying to find out is there any alternative to achieve the same.

Answer (score 5):

`case class` has an method `productIterator` to get all elements

```
address.productIterator.forall {
  case s: String => s.nonEmpty
  case _         => false
}
```